# Unable to understand this multiple select question from linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

We have a vector $v$ which belongs to the $k$ tuple. We define the following matrix:

$$P=I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$$

Here, $I$, is a $k×k$ identity matrix. Then, which of the following options is or are will be correct:

1. Inverse of $P$ is equal to $I-P$.
2. $-1$ and $1$ will be two eigenvalues of matrix.
3. Inverse of $P$ is equal to $P$.
4. $(1+P)v=v$.

Any initial hint about the what matrix $P$ represents will be appreciated. I can choose the correct options once I know what this $P$ Matrix represents. I am not able to fathom it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$P(I-P)=(I-2\frac{v v^T}{v^T v})(2\frac{v v^T}{v^T v})=2\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}-4\frac{v v^Tv v^T}{v^T v v^T v}=2\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}-4\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}=-2\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}...$

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem could be solved without "knowing" how the $P$ matrix looks like. For example, you can check whether $(I-P)P = I$ or not. 
For eigenvalues, ask yourself if it is possible to find a vector $v \ne 0$ such that
$$Pv = \lambda v$$
with $\lambda = \pm 1$ .

Comment: But the OP is given this form of matrix....

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to think about this problem geometrically which makes the solution immediate.

Let $v \cdot w$ be the usual dot product on $\mathbb R^n$ (same argument will work for $k^n$).  Notice for column vectors $$v = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}, w = \begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n\end{pmatrix}$$ we have

$$v^Tw = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n \end{pmatrix}= v \cdot w$$

Then, since matrix multiplication is associative, we have $(vv^T)w = v(v^Tw) = (v \cdot w)v$.  And therefore, $P$ can be interpreted as the linear transformation $T$ given by

$$T(w) = w - 2\frac{v \cdot w}{v \cdot v}v$$

If you define $E$ to be the orthogonal complement of $v$ in $\mathbb R^n$, then $\mathbb R^n$ is the direct sum of $E$ and $\mathbb Rv$, and you can easily check that $T$ is the unique linear transformation which fixes $E$ pointwise and sends $v$ to $-v$.

Therefore, if $v_2, ... , v_n$ is a basis for $E$, and we set $v_1 = v$, then $v_1, ... , v_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$, and the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is

$$Q =\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ & 1 \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus $Q = XPX^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $X$, and you can deduce which properties are true by looking at $Q$ instead of $P$.

The kind of linear transformation you have encountered is called a *reflection*.  It fixes a hyperplane, and sends a vector orthogonal to the hyperplane to its negative.

Comment: Good answer. These matrices are usually known as "Householder matrices"

Comment: Curious, the wikipedia article for Alston Householder describes him as "the inventor of the Householder transformation."  But the study of such transformations is much older than this guy.  For example the Weyl group of a root system is generated by reflections, and root systems go back to the 19th century.